# dgrid update from 0.3 - is it worth?

Tags: dgrid

I am currently using dgrid 0.3.21 and everything is working fine in our project.

dgrid 0.3, 0.4 and 1.x seem to be maintained in parallel.
Is there any information on how long 0.3 will be maintained?

Does anyone know advantages of the new versions?

If the new versions are worth it, we could migrate. But I don’t see any advantages.